# keep content in one line in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i keep the below content in one line

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
            Item<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="form-control input-sm" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the below content? Which part of the html are you trying to show in one line?

Comment: the checkbox and TextBox

Comment: Looking at what you have there, the form elements _should_ display in one line. So there must be something in the css which is causing them to break over multiple lines. You'll have to look for something in the css affecting those elements.

Comment: You have not provided enough code to replicate the problem. Please provide the HTML **output** from the ASP code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You'll probably need to provide the relevant CSS as well in order to allow us replicate the problem.

Comment: Yes, it is already in one line. https://jsfiddle.net/1zbq7nyd/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `nowrap` class to the container for the elements you want to be on the same line, then add this `.nowrap` class to your CSS.

```css
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline nowrap">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Item
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="form-control input-sm" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```